# Are there any common, effective methods to prevent subscription membership account sharing?

Tags: security, web, account

... without causing major UX problems?

While I'd like to think my subscribers wouldn't share their account log on details since it's keyed off their email address, I suppose it's so easy to get throw away email addresses these days there's a good chance it could happen.

Are there any common, effective methods to prevent subscription membership account sharing? My app is in C# on ASP.NET MVC, if there are some examples on that platform I'd like to see them.

Comment: You could simply block multiple sign-ons, which is what Spotify does.

Answer (score 0):

use Single Signon using an OAuth2 provided who does a descent job of preventing duplicate accounts. `Facebook`,`github` etc. can be good choices, but depends on your use case.

A biometric ID would be extremely UX friendly, and will ensure non-sharing of accounts. iPhone 5S has taken the initiative. It may become a common option in next couple of years.